# How can I use a parent name several times in an XML?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am fooling around with XML and stumbled over a problem. f.eks i want to repeat a parent name several times with the same sub childs within, only that they contain different data. how would i write that in the DTD ?

Only thing I have seen is the id attribute, but I haven't seen the executions of it in the DTD.

```
<class>
  <parent>
    <sub> aaa </sub>
    <sub2> bbb </sub2/>
  </parent>  
  <parent>
    <sub> aaa </sub>
    <sub2> bbb </sub2>
  </parent>
</class>    <!-- Added by edit -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to add several children to an element is to add a trailing `*` to the element name in the DTD. So to create a DTD with several children, you have to use a file like this (`class.dtd`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT class (parent*)>
<!ELEMENT parent (sub, sub2)>
<!ELEMENT sub (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sub2 (#PCDATA)>
```

Here, the `*` indicates that several `<parent>` elements can be children of the `<class>` element. This DTD works fine with the following XML (`test.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE class SYSTEM "class.dtd">
<class>
    <parent>
        <sub> aaa </sub>
        <sub2> bbb </sub2>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <sub> aaa </sub>
        <sub2> bbb </sub2>
    </parent>
</class>
```

You can check the correctness of the above file by using `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --dtdvalid class.dtd test.xml
```

If you'd want to have more than one `sub` or `sub2` children in the XML file, you'd need to add a trailing `*` to their element names in the DTD as well.

Comment: More specifically, `*` means zero or more. You could also use `+` which means one or more (at least one).